# How to find the cutoff frequency of my EMC filter

Tags: emc, emi-filtering, power-factor-correction

I am seeking assistance in understanding the calculation process for EMC filter capacitors and inductance. I comprehend that this filter operates with a cutoff frequency, and based on this cutoff frequency (Fcout), the values for L (inductance) and C (capacitance) can be determined.

In my specific application, I have a PFC (Power Factor Correction) with a time period of 25 kHz. I would greatly appreciate guidance on how to identify the high-frequency range and subsequently determine the appropriate dimensions for my filter.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Sincerely,
Tarik

Comment: Using a simulator will help you a lot.

Comment: Yes, I understand that using a simulator could be helpful, but I am unsure if it accurately captures the high-frequency behavior. It seems that conducting tests with an oscilloscope to observe the actual readings and then dimensioning the filter based on those results might be a more reliable approach.

Comment: The simulator, if fed with the right component models, will be accurate. That's the point of a simulation. You're doing relatively low-frequency stuff, it would seem, but for large power or radio frequency circuits, finite element RF modeling of whole PCBs is a thing.

Comment: _”with a time period of 25 kHz”_ Something is amiss here. Please check.

Comment: @winny 25Khz is and example it could be anything but still in low frequency...

Comment: @UserHomeInit your opening sentence is this: *I am seeking assistance in understanding the **calculation process** for EMC filter capacitors and inductance* and this is contradictory to your comment: * It seems that conducting tests with an oscilloscope to observe the actual readings and then dimensioning the filter based on those results might be a more reliable approach* <-- so, please decide what question you want answering. Winny is saying "25 kHz" is not a time period and, he's quite correct.

Comment: The issue at hand is that I am uncertain about how to measure high-frequency currents. When implementing a filter, it is crucial to determine what exactly needs to be filtered. In my particular situation, the only known frequency is the PWM frequency. However, I am unsure if I need to filter this specific frequency.

Comment: Before you get anywhere near implementing a filter you have to decide if you have an EMC problem then you decide what is causing the problem then you set about designing the filter. I'm unsure what your current question has got to do with measuring high-frequency currents. Commenters can only read what you have written.

Comment: Hello there. What regulation(s) are you designing to? -- This determines at least differential noise levels, if not common mode (which is a much more complicated matter).  What type of PFC are you using? -- This determines harmonic content. What means do you have to measure the currents? -- Use a LISN; read up on EMC standards e.g. CISPR 11, FCC Part 15, etc.

Comment: `When implementing a filter, it is crucial to determine what exactly needs to be filtered.` EMC filters are put to meet EMC requirement e.g. being compliant to ISO/EN-xxxxx. Know your EMC requirements first, then think about designing a filter.